# How to access mongoDB atlas from google cloud function using serverless VPC

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas, google-vpc

I have a google cloud function which needs to access the MongoDB hosted on Atlas (GCP).
This cloud function needs to access a specific API hosted outside GCP. For security reasons they need to allow the cloud functions IP address on their firewall rules.

To enable the static IP address request, I created a serverless VPC connector and configured all the egress traffic for my cloud function.

Once I configured, the connection for mongoDB from my cloud function is failing even if I allow all incoming traffic (just for testing).

I was thinking of VPC peering to allow cloud functions to access mongoDB, but I have not been able to configure it yet. The VPC pairing shows as "PENDING" state.

1. Does Serverless VPC guarantee static IP address?
2. Why am I not able to connect to mongoDB via serverless VPC connector even though all incoming traffic is allowed?
3. Can we configure VPC peering between serverless VPC and mongodb atlas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, Serverless VPC access guaranty a static IP address is you perform the correct set up (use a Cloud Nat and a router for routing the Serverless VPC Access IP-Range through Cloud Nat and use a static IP in Cloud Nat)
2. You aren't able to reach MongoDB via serverless VPC connector because your routes aren't well defined, and because of the point 3
3. You can perform a peering between MongoDB Atlas and your VPC. For this, [follow this page](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/). If you peering is in pending state, I think that is because the GCP part has not been performed. Then define correctly your route and be sure that your firewall allow communication, and that should work!

Comment: Thanks. I haven't much of network configuration, however the things which I have done so far are :  

I have added an egress rule on firewall essentially allowing the Atlas CIDR 192.168.0.0/16 for all traffic

On the Atlas I have whitelisted the IP range for us-central1 (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ip-ranges)

I still see the status as Inactive on GCP and pending on mongoDB

Comment: Open egress firewall rules and making a peering is different. Follow all the steps for having a stable peering connexion.

Comment: I haven't had much luck on this front yet. I have added the required things as per the document and whitelisted the VPC CIDR on atlas. I still see this "Inactive". Let me see if I can find any more logs on this

Comment: I was able to get the static IP and peering done. I was missing the Cloud NAT, and no wonder it was not working. As mentioned, it needs Serverless VPC and Cloud NAT to ensure there is internet access for all egresss. Once NAT was defined, the rest started working as per the documentation